# How to use git bash in c++ code?

Tags: c++, git, bash

Hello I will make a software in c++ that use the git bash to make a backup.
But how can I use git bash commands on windows in c++ Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this API in your application.

https://libgit2.github.com/

> `libgit2` is a portable, pure `C` implementation of the Git core methods provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, **allowing you to write native speed custom Git applications** in any language which supports C bindings.